# Use renditionDownload url for Attachments instead of ContentDocuments

Tags: lightning-web-components, files, preview

I'm trying to use **renditionDownload** URL to preview files from a custom data table and it's working fine with ContentDocuments but not with Attachments.

This is my URL code generator:

```
return `/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload?rendition=THUMB240BY180&versionId=${this.fileId}&operationContext=CHATTER&page=0`
```

Where fileId is LatestPublishVersionId for ContentDocuments and Id for Attachment (this last one not working at all).

Is there a way to make this work with attachments too? Even if it's based on generating a different URL?

Regards,

Comment: Do you want to have preview for attachments (1st page only + smaller size) or a URL to view/download it? If last one, then `/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=<att id>` can help

Comment: @kurunve Hi! I want to have a preview for attachments

Comment: I do not think SF has such a feature at the moment

Comment: @kurunve That's what I thought but thanks for the confirmation!

Answer (score 0):

[Kurunve](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/18189/kurunve), Who to preview a ContentDocument with not just 1st page only?
This just preview 1st page of the PDF:
"/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload"